# How to output the last element of an unordered list to the console?

Tags: jquery

I've tried this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$lastElement=$( "ul li" ).last();
console.log($lastElement);
</script>
```

This is the list:

```
<ul id="cool-list">
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
<li>item3</li>
</ul>
```

I expected the output `item3` on the console. Instead it shows `r.fn.init [prevObject: r.fn.init(0)]`.

That seems like an OOP concept that I don't understand. Is there a simpler way to do it? Or am I'm doing it entirely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when you use a jQuery method to select, find, or filter down a collection of elements, you're given a jQuery collection of the new elements in return. That's what's happening here. `$lastElement` is not an HTMLElement; it's a jQuery collection, a collection which contains one element.

It gives you a jQuery collection in return because you may want to use additional jQuery methods on the result.

If you want to extract the element, access the `[0]`th element of the collection:

```js
$lastElement = $("ul li").last();
console.log($lastElement[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="cool-list">
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
</ul>
```

If you only want the *text* of the found element, use the jQuery method `.text()` instead:

```js
$lastElement = $("ul li").last();
console.log($lastElement.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="cool-list">
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
</ul>
```

But this is a pretty silly trivial task to require jQuery for. You might find it easier to start with the basics of vanilla JS instead: elements can be selected with `querySelector`:

```js
const lastElement = document.querySelector("ul li:last-child");
console.log(lastElement.textContent);
```

```html
<ul id="cool-list">
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
</ul>
```